# Coding in Rstudio

Tags: rstudio

```
factor(x=c("High School", "College", "Masters", "Doctorate"),
         + levels=c("High School", "College", "Masters", "Doctorate"),
         + ordered=TRUE)
```

THE ERROR -

> Error: unexpected ')' in "       + ordered=TRUE)"

Comment: This code was given in R for everyone book by JARED LANDER. I tried to retrieve the same with Rstudio but I am encountering this error. please help

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] .. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `+` from your code. That `+` is meant to indicate that it is the continuation of a line and is merely aesthetic.

Use `?factor` for information on parameters and syntax for using a function.